# How can I organize a list of strings alphabetically starting on a specific letter?

Tags: python, string, slice, alphabetical

Example, if I have:

`x = ['5 Gabriela', '4 Isabel', '1 Daniel', '1 Gabriel']`

I want my output list to be organized by the names, not the numbers:

`output_list = ['1 Daniel', '1 Gabriel', '5 Gabriela', '4 Isabel']`

I tried doing some slicing but then my output list doesn't have the numbers:

```
names = []
for k in range (0, len(sum_sor)):
    start = x[k][2::]
    names.append(start)
    y = sorted(names)
print(y)
```

Output: 
`y = ['Daniel', 'Gabriel', 'Gabriela', 'Ixchelle']`

Comment: Note your current list is not actually sorted numerically, it's a lexographic sort still but starting from the digits

Comment: Is it a typo that your output lists a different name than the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with `key` being a lambda returning the name for each element of `x`

`sorted(x, key=lambda y: y.split()[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two additional ways, using regexes, and the `sorted` function.

The following will first remove the digits from the strings, and order the elements from `x` according to their digit-free version.

```
sorted(x, key=lambda y: re.sub("\d+", "", y))
```

This one will first look for a sequence of non-digit characters, and then order the element from `x` according to that sequence.

```
sorted(x, key=lambda y: re.search("\D+", y).group())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am more of a new to python but I would make a function to get the 3rd letter. Assuming each has this way:

```
def get_letter(sample_string):
    return sample_string[2]
```

now we can use this to sort the list using this function as a key:

```
x = ['5 Gabriela', '4 Isabel', '1 Daniel', '1 Gabriel']
output_list = sorted(x,key=get_letter)
```

Hope I helped, good luck!